# uiRouter not setting values when I change state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I would have thought this would be easy however I am obviously doing something wrong, no matter what I do I can't get the "personId" variable in the conttroller when I change state. I can see it in the URL so you think it would be OK but it's always undefined. Hopefully someone can see the mistake - here is the config for the state

```
$stateProvider.state('quickScreen', {
    params: {
        hideAjaxContainer: "true",
        personId: {}
    },
    //url: "/Components/QuickScreen/{personId}",
    url: "/Components/QuickScreen/:personId",
    views: {
        angularContentContainer: {
            templateUrl: "/Components/QuickScreen/index.html",
            controller: "quickScreenController",
            resolve: {
                name: function ($stateParams) {
                    return $stateParams.personId;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and this is the controller

```
var quickScreenController = function ($scope, $stateParams) {
console.log("quickScreenController loaded: " + $stateParams.personId);
```

};

It is possible that because my URL's end up looking like this "http://localhost:1790/Search2#/Components/QuickScreen/5a114c4f-44c2-477a-97e5-a19500995016" it doesn't work but I don't know. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any bad in your syntax. Even more, I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vttnI9MH0B6qLGYxcaRw?p=preview) and this is **working**

```
  $stateProvider.state('quickScreen', {
    params: {
      hideAjaxContainer: "true",
      personId: {}
    },
    //url: "/Components/QuickScreen/{personId}",
    url: "/Components/QuickScreen/:personId",
    views: {
      angularContentContainer: {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        //templateUrl: "/Components/QuickScreen/index.html",
        controller: "quickScreenController",
        resolve: {
          name: function($stateParams) {
            return $stateParams.personId;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vttnI9MH0B6qLGYxcaRw?p=preview). *If this still won't help, update that plunker to reproduce the issue... ready to assist...*